# Changing the target framework from .Net Core MVC 3.0 to .Net Core MVC 2.0 in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Trying to create a .Net Core MVC 2.0 project in VSCode, ran the below two commands in terminal

```
dotnet new mvc -o MvcTest
code -r MvcTest
```

The above two commands ended up creating a 3.0 target framework project(understandable since 3.0 is the latest)

But how can I create a lower version like 2.0, it's easier in Visual studio where we can change the target framework.

Need workaround for doing this in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall you need to have a `global.json` where you are standing in the CLI to define lower SDK versions.

You can create one from the CLI with `dotnet new globaljson`

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x